# Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I am facing a error in javascript....
when the javascript function calling  it is not working  but if i set a `alert('someting');` within the function then the script is running but if i comment off the alert within the script,

is not working. 
what is the solution.......

Comment: What is the Javascript-error-message?

Comment: You'll need to post some code. Just enough to reproduce the problem, if possible.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What happens? Where's the code?

Comment: Then post some code that we can find the error

Comment: Where is the code that fails?! What happens if you put that alert call to be last statement not the first? Does it still show? If not move it up until it shows and let us see the code immediately below.

Answer (score 1):

put you code in try.. catch block and check is there any exception

```
  try
  {
  //Run some code here
  }
catch(err)
  {
  //Handle errors here
   alert(err);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in load event:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your code...
};
```

Or put your js code at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running with firefox, you won't know whether error occur in this function or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you include the alert your most likely giving elements on the page you are loading time to appear which are probably required for you JS to actually run.

You could try using:

```
window.onload = function(){    
     //drop some code in here 
}
```

or you could use jquery and wrap your code into a document.ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

You will need to load the latest version of jquery onto your page if you were to you this method.